# don't execute jquery if x is in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to not run this script if the URL is http://convoy.nyc/commerce/show-cart , but something isn't working correctly

```
if (window.location.indexOf('show-cart') == -1){
}
else {
    window.onload = function(){
    $( ".sqs-money-native" ).append( " per person" );
}

}
```

Comment: can you post the html code

Comment: @RiteshK just updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it, you where missing the .href:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('show-cart') === -1){
    window.onload = function(){
        $( ".sqs-money-native" ).append( " per person" );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. still not working for me however. any ideas?